# Drupal FB-Connect and IE

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, facebook, drupal-modules

i have installed the fbconnect module under drupal 6.

i have added

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" 
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php print $language->language ?>" 
                    lang="<?php print $language->language ?>" dir="<?php print $language->dir ?>">
```

to every page template, and include `$closure` tags...

still the connect button will not display in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, i've read them all.

today i solved the issue by installing the dev version of jquery update, so that jquery 1.3 was available.

i'm pretty sure that .trigger() was not available in 1.2 and it is used in the initialization of the fb class.

thanks for checking.